# How can I avoid focusing on slickGoTo event

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in order to perform some actions with a carousel.

I recorded a [video](https://monosnap.com/file/NK1mTSyXUJINa9q4gEUVaHvOyF32iY) of the behaviour I want to avoid.
Is that weird focus action it makes when you click on the tabs. All I need is that if you click on any of the tabs, the focus doesn't go anywhere so the screen doesn't make that scroll down action.

I am using this function to go to the slide I need which is causing the focusing glitch I don't need:

```
var handleTabsClick = function() {
    $('.product-details--P3 .product-tabs__link').on('click', function() {
        var index = $(this).data('index');
        $('.slick').slick('slickGoTo', index, false);
    });
};
```

And this is the html for those tabs

```
<ul class="product-tabs js-tabs">
    <li class="js-tab">
        <a class="product-tabs__link" href="#" data-index="0">
            Advantage <span>SafaBalance</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="js-tab">
        <a class="product-tabs__link" href="#" data-index="1">
            Advantage <span>Plus</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="js-tab">
        <a class="product-tabs__link" href="#" data-index="2">
            Advantage <span>Relationships</span> </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

These tabs are separate from the slick functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the href has `#` so every click will add `#` in url which replaces your browser's url. So replace the `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"` from your anchor tags like,

```
<ul class="product-tabs js-tabs">
    <li class="js-tab">
        <a class="product-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-index="0">
            Advantage <span>SafaBalance</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="js-tab">
        <a class="product-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-index="1">
            Advantage <span>Plus</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="js-tab">
        <a class="product-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-index="2">
            Advantage <span>Relationships</span> </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in your click event like

```
$('.product-details--P3 .product-tabs__link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    $('.slick').slick('slickGoTo', index, false);
});
```